# Prove that for n ≥ 3, $K_n$ is the union of cycles $C_3,\ldots,C_{n − 1}$, a path of length 2 and an edge.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

We managed to prove that $K_n$ and the union of cycles  $C_3$ to $C_{n − 1}$ have same number of edges:

$ n \choose 2 $ = $\sum_{1}^{n-1}k = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$

We know we need to prove it by induction, but the priority right now is to understand whether this condition (same number of edges) is sufficient to reply the questions. **How can we arrange the cycles in a specific way without "breaking the rings", to make the complete graph $K_n$**?

I read the following post but I don't really understand the proof:
[$K_n$ for odd $n$ $ϵ$ $Z_+$ is a disjoint union (of edges) of collections of Hamiltonian cycles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2583036/k-n-for-odd-n-%cf%b5-z-is-a-disjoint-union-of-edges-of-collections-of-ham)

Comment: What are $K_n$ and $C_n$?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco: The complete graph on $n$ vertices and the cyclic graph on $n$ vertices, respectively.

Comment: Thank you Brian, this is precisely what was meant.

Comment: No, and I am not sure it is true either. The problem statement says "is it true that..."

Comment: I am sorry, asked the teacher and saw it was untrue. Can you explain that instead please?

Comment: I did not figure it out but I it is not true according to the teacher notes.

Comment: If you explain to me in an official reply why it does not work I will give you the bounty, you really deserve it :D!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a graph $G$ is decomposed into cycles and paths, then each cycle contributes $0$ or $2$ to the degree of each vertex of $G$, and each path contributes $0$ or $2$ to the degree of each vertex except its endpoints. Therefore, a graph which can be decomposed into two paths and a number of cycles can have at most four vertices of odd degree, namely the endpoints of the paths. Since every vertex of $K_n$ has odd degree when $n$ is even, it follows that the statement is false for all even $n\gt4$.

On the other hand, the statement is easily seen to be true for $n=3,4,5,7$. For instance, $K_7$ can be decomposed into $5$ cycles of lengths $3,3,4,5,6$ as follows. Call the vertices $A,B,C,D,E,F,G$; then the cycles are $ABDA$, $ACEA$, $AFCGA$, $BEGDFB$, $BCDEFGB$. (Of course you can
break one of the $3$-cycles into a path of length $1$ and a path of length $2$.)

In fact, the statement seems to be true for all odd $n\ge3$. It follows from one of the general results of Darryn Bryant, Daniel Horsley, and William Pettersson in their 182-page paper [Decomposition of complete graphs into cycles of arbitrary lengths](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.3709) that for odd $n\ge3$ the complete graph $K_n$ can be decomposed into a cycle of length $3$ and $n-3$ additional cycles of lengths $3,4,\dots,n-1$. Quoting their abstract:

> We show that the complete graph on $n$ vertices can be decomposed into $t$ cycles of specified lengths $m_1,\dots,m_t$ if and only if $n$ is odd, $3\le m_i\le n$ for $i=1,\dots,t$, and $m_1+\cdots+m_t=\binom n2$.
> We also show that the complete graph on $n$ vertices can be decomposed into a perfect matching and $t$ cycles of specified lengths $m_1,\dots,m_t$ if and only if $n$ is even, $3\le m_i\le n$ for $i=1,\dots,t$, and $m_1+\dots+m_t=\binom n2-\frac n2$.

I have not studied the proofs, which are long and complicated with many cases.